# convert ISO date to T00:00:00Z in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

i have a date time format such as "2021-08-02T05:56:10.070Z" ((new Date()).toISOString()) how can i convert it to "2021-08-02T00:00:00Z".

i read one is ISOstring and another is UTCstring. but how to convert between the two.

Comment: Both of these are ISO 8601 format. They just have different times. One is midnight, the other isn't.

Comment: is it the `.070` you want to get rid of, or the ALL of the time?

Comment: `((new Date()).toISOString()).replace(/T.*/, 'T00:00:00Z')`

Comment: @Bravo how to get rid of .070 ?

Comment: so, that's all you want to get rid of? `((new Date()).toISOString()).replace(/\..*/, 'Z')`